# Exclude a directory recursively from 301 redirect using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I just launched a new website (built on Wix) at the address http://lifeworks.life. I have archived the old site (WordPress) at http://lifeworkslearningcetner.com/archive, moving all the files except one .htaccess file from the root folder at http://lifeworkslearningcenter.com to keep the redirects and SEO juice flowing.

I have the specific redirects working, as well as the root-level redirect. But now, the URL http://lifeworkslearningcenter.com/archive redirects to https://www.lifeworks.life/archive, which does not exist and ends in a 404.

Here is the .htaccess code I'm using. What I want is to be able to access the WordPress site in the /archive folder normally, both the front end and the back end.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifeworkslearningcenter\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifeworkslearningcenter\.com$
RewriteRule ^about-lifeworks$ "https\:\/\/www\.lifeworks\.life\/team\.html" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifeworkslearningcenter\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifeworkslearningcenter\.com$
RewriteRule ^services$ "https\:\/\/www\.lifeworks\.life\/services\.html" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifeworkslearningcenter\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifeworkslearningcenter\.com$
RewriteRule ^methodology$ "https\:\/\/www\.lifeworks\.life\/approach\.html" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifeworkslearningcenter\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifeworkslearningcenter\.com$
RewriteRule ^sign-up$ "https\:\/\/www\.lifeworks\.life\/enroll\.html" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifeworkslearningcenter\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifeworkslearningcenter\.com$
RewriteRule ^rates-and-policies$ "https\:\/\/www\.lifeworks\.life\/policies\.html" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifeworkslearningcenter\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifeworkslearningcenter\.com$
RewriteRule ^contact-us$ "https\:\/\/www\.lifeworks\.life\/contact\.html" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifeworkslearningcenter\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifeworkslearningcenter\.com$
RewriteRule ^blog$ "https\:\/\/www\.lifeworks\.life\/blog\.html" [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 / http://lifeworks.life/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last statement (`Redirect ...`) has no condition and therefore always redirects you to lifeworks.life.
In order to exclude **/archive** requests from a redirect, you could use something like the following instead of your Redirect statement:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^lifeworks\.life$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/archive
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://lifeworks.life/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't seem to do anything. I cleared my cache, and I moved it to the bottom of the .htaccess file, to no avail.

Comment: I forgot to add -- I tried replacing lifeworks.life with lifeworkslearningcenter.com, since that's the site where I need to exclude the folder.

Comment: The `!^lifeworks\.life$` is there to prevent redirect loops and means "if it is not lifeworks.life". You must keep it that way.

Comment: Gotcha. OK, I tried adding your exact code, at the bottom of the file, and cleared my cache, and it's not working.

Comment: Just to be sure, you removed your `Redirect` statement at the bottom of the file?

Comment: Yes, I removed both the Redirect statement and the wildcard redirect I had in place.

Comment: Can you give an example of a Request that is not working and tell what exactly is not working?